# force docker to log to journald when started as systemd job

Tags: docker, systemd

When I run the docker container like this `docker compose up --build` all the output goes to the screen.

But we have an in-house standard that all jobs must be systemd, so I "wrapped" like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Anglo1
After=network.target
After=rc-local.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=always
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/mnt/DockerJobs/Anglo1
LimitNOFILE=5000000
LogRateLimitIntervalSec=0
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker compose up --build
TimeoutStopSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can start and stop the job, but the output that was going to screen is not shown by  `journalctl -u anglo1.service -f` as I would expect, instead it appears here `docker logs 8c4e5f143a86`, so Docker is detecting how the container is run and treating it differently if it is run on the command line vs from systemd.

How do I make the output go to the journal as normal?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your `[Service]` section

```
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
```

Then reload systemed daemon with this command

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart your service to get the log

```
sudo systemctl anglo1.service
```

Then check the journalctl with

```
journalctl -u anglo1.service
```

Comment: nope, says: No journal files were found.

Comment: and the container is running normally?

Comment: yes, as i can see the log output using ```docker logs --tail 10 1c684f007cf2``` where that weird number is container from ```docker container ls```

Comment: Can you try to update the `ExecStart` command from `/usr/bin/docker compose up --build` to `/usr/bin/docker compose up --build | systemd-cat -t anglo1.service` and reload restart and test again.

Comment: same as before :(

Comment: I think I cant help any further with this.

Comment: I guess, you need to enable the journal driver with Docker https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/